# Multiple group homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, functions

I need to prove or disprove the following:

Let f and g be group homomorphisms from G to H where (G, ·)(H, ∗). Define h : G → H by h(x)=f(x)∗g(x). Then h is also a homomorphism.

I want to say that h is a homomorphism if it is a function of multiple homomorphisms on the same group, but I am unsure about how to do so. Any suggestions would help!

Answer (score 2):

Let $G$ be the free group on generators $x$ and $y$.  Let $f$ be the identity from $G$ to $G$.  Let $g:G\rightarrow G$ be defined by $g(x)=x$, $g(y)=xy$.  Then
$$
h(xy)=f(xy)g(xy)=f(x)f(y)g(x)g(y)=xyxxy
$$
and
$$
h(x)h(y)=f(x)g(x)f(y)g(y)=xxyxy.
$$

Answer (score 1):

You need to show that $h$ respects the group law. So you need to look at
$$ h(x\cdot y) = f(x\cdot y)*g(x\cdot y) = f(x)*f(y)* g(x)* g(y) = \dots $$
from here you notice that your claim doesn't hold in general. 
It does if you require $H$ to be abelian.

Comment: But, $f(x)f(y)g(x)g(y)$ may not be the same as $f(x)g(x)f(y)g(y)$ if the group is not abelian.

Comment: I wanted to suggest the OP that one crucial assumption on $H$ is required

Comment: "prove or disprove"